# How to sort application startup forms list in VB.NET project

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I can't find the option/way to sort the list of forms to select the startup form:

[image: Please click to see the screenshot]

Is there a way to sort it because I have to keep changing between forms during testing, which is very difficult to find in the list because of unsorted list.

Comment: It is a known annoyance: [Startup Object, Form list not alphabetical](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/217890/startup-object-form-list-not-alphabetical.html). Upvote that issue if you want it to have a chance of being fixed.

Comment: Use Sub Main so you can make the startup form anything you want.  If you don't know how to write it then look at the Main() method of a C# project.

Comment: @AndrewMorton Done! This has always bothered me.

Comment: @HansPassant In Program.cs a class called Program has a Sub Main `new Form1().Show();`

In VB I find the following
1. Application.myapp
under the <MyApplicationData> tag
<MainForm>Form2</MainForm> changes when project properties are changed.

Comment: @HansPassant 2. Application.Designer.vb (which says "do not modify it directly")
there is a Partial class MyApplication
containing `Sub OnCreateMainForm()
            Me.MainForm = Global.TestCode2.Form2
        End Sub`
also changes when project project properties are changed.

3. ApplicationEvents.vb has another part of the MyApplication partial class which mentions a number of event which can be handled but not Sub Main.

Where exactly would I add a Sub Main and will it change the other files that mention the start up form?

Comment: @AndrewMorton Thanks for the link..will do.